# Can't load @tensorflow/tfjs in angularjs app

Tags: javascript, tensorflow

I was following the Youtube video from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_XM3Bu-4yc) to learn how to build a basic tensorflowjs app. And I am currently at 3:22 of the video. I checked the console and the console said the following

> ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(2,21): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@tensorflow/tfjs'.
>
> src/app/app.component.ts(10,14): error TS2420: Class 'AppComponent' incorrectly implements interface 'OnInit'.
>
> Property 'ngOnInit' is missing in type 'AppComponent'.

I did follow the video strictly and I couldn't understand why I got this error. Here is my app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'app';
}
```

How can I eliminate the errors?

Comment: dude this is not angular.js , this is angular 2 or 6

Comment: For anyone seeing this later on, if you installed `@tensorflow/tfjs`, make sure you also run `npm i @tensorflow/tfjs-node`.

Answer (score 0):

The first error means you haven't installed the tensorflow library in the project you are working in. To resolve that issue, go into the directory of the project using a terminal and issue the `npm install @tensorflow/tfjs` command to install the library.

The second error is because you have your `AppComponent` implementing `OnInit`, but there is no `ngOnInit` function in the component. You either have to add an `ngOnInit` function (it can be an empty function) or remove `implements OnInit`

Comment: i did install tensorflow. And i checked the directory and it is inside the node_modules file, which is same as the @angular/core. However, when i compile the app, it said it can’t resolved the module in the app/ directory, which is the location of the app.component.ts.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it. After I run

> npm install @tensorflow/tfjs

to install tensorflowjs. I need to run an extra "npm install" and the AngularJS can find the @tensorflow/tfjs library.

Edit 1 :

I also changed the package.json file. I changed the version of tensorflowjs from the github one to "^0.6.1" before running "npm install".